# Linux Framebuffer Inefficient Frame Grabbing

Tags: c, linux, framebuffer

I'm attempting to repeatedly grab a frame from the Linux framebuffer, but it's taking about a second for each frame.

While I didn't expect 60FPS, I was hoping for more than 60FPM. Is this normal? I'm using open source video drivers; my GPU is an AMD 280X and my CPU is an AMD 8320 @ 4.4GHz.

My code looks something like this:

```
static uint8_t *previous_buffer;
static uint8_t *fbp;

static long int location = 0;
long int screensize = 0;

int sf = open("/dev/fb0",O_RDWR);
struct fb_var_screeninfo vinfo;
struct fb_fix_screeninfo finfo;

ioctl(sf, FBIOGET_FSCREENINFO, &finfo);
ioctl(sf, FBIOGET_VSCREENINFO, &vinfo);

screensize = finfo.smem_len;

fbp = mmap(0, screensize, PROT_READ | PROT_WRITE, MAP_SHARED, sf, (off_t)0);

previous_buffer = malloc(screensize);

bytespp = (vinfo.bits_per_pixel / 8);

for(int x = 0; x < vinfo->xres * bytespp; x+=bytespp)
    for(int y = 0; y < vinfo->yres * finfo->line_length; y+=finfo->line_length){
        //printf("xoff: %d yoff:%d x:%d y:%d\n", xoff, yoff, x, y);
        location = x + y + off;
        //printf("Location: %lu\n", location);
        if(*((uint32_t*)(fbp+location)) != *((uint32_t*)(previous_buffer+location))){
            memcpy((fbp+location), (previous_buffer+location), 4); // sizeof(uint32_t)
            d1++;
        }
    }
```

My full code is available [here](https://github.com/nashley/remotefb/blob/get_pixels/main.c), but I think the loops are the important part.

Additionally, I tried running a program from [this website](http://betteros.org/tut/graphics1.php) which sets each pixel to pink, and the loop itself only took 7ms (even though it performed multiplication and division in each run of its loop):

```
#include <linux/fb.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdint.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <sys/mman.h>
#include <sys/ioctl.h>

inline uint32_t pixel_color(uint8_t r, uint8_t g, uint8_t b, struct fb_var_screeninfo *vinfo)
{
    return (r<<vinfo->red.offset) | (g<<vinfo->green.offset) | (b<<vinfo->blue.offset);
}

int main()
{
    struct fb_fix_screeninfo finfo;
    struct fb_var_screeninfo vinfo;

    int fb_fd = open("/dev/fb0",O_RDWR);

    //Get variable screen information
    ioctl(fb_fd, FBIOGET_VSCREENINFO, &vinfo);
    vinfo.grayscale=0;
    vinfo.bits_per_pixel=32;
    ioctl(fb_fd, FBIOPUT_VSCREENINFO, &vinfo);
    ioctl(fb_fd, FBIOGET_VSCREENINFO, &vinfo);

    ioctl(fb_fd, FBIOGET_FSCREENINFO, &finfo);

    long screensize = vinfo.yres_virtual * finfo.line_length;

    uint8_t *fbp = mmap(0, screensize, PROT_READ | PROT_WRITE, MAP_SHARED, fb_fd, (off_t)0);

    int x,y;

    for (x=0;x<vinfo.xres;x++)
        for (y=0;y<vinfo.yres;y++)
        {
            long location = (x+vinfo.xoffset) * (vinfo.bits_per_pixel/8) + (y+vinfo.yoffset) * finfo.line_length;
            *((uint32_t*)(fbp + location)) = pixel_color(0xFF,0x00,0xFF, &vinfo);
        }

    return 0;
}
```

Is writing to the framebuffer really that much faster than reading from it?

Comment: you are doing expensive operations (multiplications) within each loop; avoid them by incrementing the pointer per pixel and line. You should swap the x and y loops for this.

Comment: Two suggestions: Firstly, remove those `uint32_t` pointer casts, they make the code unreadable. Then, remove the `if` check in the inner loop, its overhead is probably greater than the time you try to save with it. Lastly, use `memcpy()` or even one of the aligned variants provided by GCC and copy a whole line, that should boost performance a bit. That said, where exactly does your code spend its time? Did you profile the code?

Comment: @UlrichEckhardt I removed the `uint32_t` pointer casts and replaced the if statement with a `memcpy` from the framebuffer pointer to the previous buffer pointer with a size of `uint32_t` (granted, it's still each pixel and not the whole line), and the performance was about equal (i.e., 990 ms).

Comment: @ensc I tried both your (and Ulrich Eckhardt's) recommendations, and they aren't improving the time at all. I thought that it had significantly improved performance until I realized that I didn't account for the changing loop boundaries after I changed their increments. Have either of you had any experience with reading Linux framebuffers? Unless my most recent code is still buggy, I don't think that reading the framebuffer gets any faster.

Comment: what about using loop for `previous_buffer` and then with one call of `memcpy` copy data to frame buffer?

Comment: Wait: Are you using one `memcpy()` call per pixel? That would be totally wrong! As much as possible, you should copy adjacent bytes/pixels in one collective `memcpy()` call. Using separate call prevents optimizations that the compiler could otherwise use. Loading and storing to distant addresses (like pixels only one Y position apart!) causes cache misses. Both are bad for performance.

Comment: @UlrichEckhardt I tried timing just a memcpy of the entire framebuffer, and it took 585ms. Wouldn't this be the fastest possible operation for obtaining a snapshot of the screen (nothing else but a single memcpy was run)?

Comment: Probably yes. I don't know if there is padding between the lines which would be worth skipping. Also, just curious, how many bytes does the code copy?

Comment: @UlrichEckhardt I'm using fb_fix_screeninfo.smem_len, the size of the framebuffer's memory, which in my case is 8294400 for a 1440x900 framebuffer.

Comment: @UlrichEckhardt I tested copying the framebuffer into memory and then copying the memory into another section of memory, and it took 581ms and then 3ms respectively. Unless I'm suffering from severe oversight, it seems like the framebuffer really is just that slow.

Comment: framebuffer memory is usually DMA coherent memory (data will be written and read directly to/from DRAM).  So, it this memory is slower than *normal* memory (which is usually cached).

Comment: @ensc So is there no faster way to get the framebuffer data? Timing a tool like scrot (Xorg screenshot application) takes less time (.245s). I thought that Xorg used the framebuffer, but it doesn't appear to in my setup. How can I read what Xorg is using (preferably without talking to Xorg)?

Comment: @ensc Also, isn't DRAM quite fast? Why would it be that much slower (even if it has to copied into RAM)?

Answer (score 1):

My (untested) suggestion for the loop:

```
void const *start = (fbp + vinfo->yoffset * finfo->line_length + 
                     vinfo->xoffset * bytespp);
void       *out = previous_buffer;
size_t     xres_bytes = vinfo->xres * bytespp;
size_t     d_stride = finfo->line_length - xres_bytes;

if (d_stride == 0 && allow_memcpy) {
        memcpy(out, start, finfo->line_length * vinfo->yres);
}  else {
        for (int y = 0; y < vinfo->yres_virtual; ++y) {
                start += d_stride;
                if (allow_memcpy) {
                        out = mempcpy(out, start, xres_bytes);
                        start += xres_bytes;
                } else {
                        /* or do the #include thing below here */
                        for (int x = 0; x < vinfo->xres_virtual; ++x) {
                                switch (bytesbpp) {
                                case 1:  out = mempcpy(out, start, 1); break;
                                case 2:  out = mempcpy(out, start, 2); break;
                                case 3:  out = mempcpy(out, start, 3); break;
                                case 4:  out = mempcpy(out, start, 4); break;
                                default: out = mempcpy(out, start, bytesbpp); break;
                                }
                                start += bytesbpp;
                        }
                }
        }  
}
```

When you want to optimize it further, you can put the inner `x` loop into an extra file (e.g. `inner-x-loop.inc.h`) and include it like

```
if (bytesbpp == 1) {
#include "inner-x-loop.inc.h"
} else if (bytesbpp == 2) {
#include "inner-x-loop.inc.h"
} else if (bytesbpp == 3) {
#include "inner-x-loop.inc.h"
} else if (bytesbpp == 4) {
#include "inner-x-loop.inc.h"
} else
#include "inner-x-loop.inc.h"
}
```

Enumerating the `bytesbpp` allows the compiler to inline the `mempcpy()`.

Comment: What is allow_memcpy? I set it to one in order to test your code. For some reason, gcc is complaining about mempcpy being an implicit function despite the fact that I've included `string.h`, so I haven't gotten it to compile yet.

Comment: `allow_memcpy` should be a compile time constant (e.g. `#define allow_memcpy (true)` or `static bool const allow_memcpy = true`).  `mempcpy` requires `_GNU_SOURCE`; e.g. build with `-std=gnu99` or define it manually.

Comment: I compiled your code (with a few [modifications](https://gist.github.com/nashley/63fadf31e8b2f188d6ceeaf6fa11e581)) and it took 441ms, which, while faster than any other implementation I've found, is not exactly fast. Do you get similar results on your own machine? Could it be a problem with my setup?